# SQL Server: Convert jpeg blob to png

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For database migration, I need to convert jpeg image blobs to png blobs. Can this be done pure SQL server way or do I need to have external assemblies to do the conversion?

Comment: Well - you might be able to do something using CLR components, but I would think it's still too limiting and you'll need external application

Answer (score 1):

There is no native SQL Server way to perform this conversion. SQL Server knows nothing of image data and just sees those blobs as a pile of bytes.

You should do this conversion as a separate step after the rest of your conversion and use a tool appropriate for the task. That means a program or script which can query the data, perform the conversion (perhaps using a utility like ImageMagick), then update the data. An even safer option would be to create a new column for the PNG and insert the converted image there, rather than overwriting the JPEG; later, when you're satisfied that no one is using the JPEG any longer, you can drop the column from the table.